# How to report the Short term Capital loss (incurred during a perticular time slot of the Year) in IT return

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, capital-gains-tax

I have got some short term capital gains (Say Rs.100) during a particular F.Y.

In the I.T. return form it is required to enter the breakup of this into four time slots ( i.e From 1st Apr.to 15th Sept,16th sept. to 15th Dec.,16th Dec to 15th Mar. and 16th Mar. to 31st Dec.).

In my case let us say this breakup is Rs.120, Rs -80, Rs 35 & Rs 25 thus totalling to Rs.100.

In the above case there is Short term capital loss of Rs.80 during the second slot. However the ITR 4 does not allow this negative entry to be made.

I request the learned people to please suggest me the solution for the above issue as per Income Tax rules.

Answer (score 1):

> In the I.T. return form it is required to enter the breakup of this into four time slots ( i.e From 1st Apr.to 15th Sept, 16th sept. to 15th Dec., 16th Dec to 15th Mar. and 16th Mar. to 31st Dec.).

Yes this is required. The intent is to capture late tax payments. For example if one makes a gain of Rs 1,00,000 in April; the taxes should be paid before 15th Sept. Else there is a late payment penalty of 1% per month.

> In my case let us say this breakup is Rs.120, Rs -80, Rs 35 & Rs 25 thus totalling to Rs.100.
>
> In the above case there is Short term capital loss of Rs.80 during the
>   second slot. However the ITR 4 does not allow this negative entry to
>   be made.

Yes the ITR [2 or 4] does not cater to this situation. If the amount involved are small then adjust this accordingly, i.e. Rs 100, and then Zero for other 3 periods. If the amounts are large, please consult a CA.